# Does the proof of MCT need linearity of Lebesgue integration?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

This is an exercise in real analysis:

> Let $(X,{\mathcal B},\mu)$ be a measure space and let $f,g\in L^1(X,{\mathcal B},\mu)$ be such that $f,g:X\to {\Bbb R}$. Show that for all $\alpha,\beta\in{\Bbb R}$
>   $$
> \int_X\alpha\  f+\beta \ g\  d\mu=\alpha\int_X\ f\ d\mu+\beta\int_X g\ d\mu.
> $$

One way to do it is prove it for the simple functions first, and then the non-negative functions, and then the general cases.

In the step of showing 
$$
\int_Xf+gd\mu=\int_Xfd\mu+\int_Xgd\mu
$$
when $f$ and $g$ are non-negative, one might argue that since we have nonnegative increasing simple functions $\{f_n\},\{g_n\}$ such that 
$$
\lim f_n=f,\quad \lim g_n=g,
$$
we can use Lebesgue Monotone Convergence Theorem here as long as we've shown the linearity for simple functions:
[EDITED according to Thomas E.]
$$
\begin{align}
\int_X f+g d\mu&=\int_X\lim(f_n+g_n)d\mu\\
&=\lim\int_X  f_n+  g_n d\mu\\
&=\lim\int_X  f_n+  \lim\int_Xg_n d\mu\\
&=\int_X\lim f_nd\mu+\int_X\lim g_nd\mu\\
&=\int_Xfd\mu+\int_Xg d\mu.
\end{align}
$$

Here is my question:

> Does the proof of MCT need the linearity of Lebesgue integration so that this might be a circular proof?

Comment: One can prove the monotone convergence theorem without using the linearity of the integral. Bartle proves it without using linearity in "The Elements of Integration and Lebesgue Measure".

Comment: I wouldn't use the MCT *before* the Lebesgue integral has been defined and its fundamental properties have been established. It seems kind of premature. However it is only a matter of taste as I cannot guarantee you that this approach is circular. Actually I think that the contrary is true and that this reasoning is *not* circular.

Comment: In the long equality, you probably want to take the limit outside of the integrand, because otherwise you are not using MCT at all.

Answer (score 1):

[Partial answer.]
When I revisit this question, I don't even remember how on earth I came up with such question. In lots of the stand texts in measure theory, convergence theorems (such as MCT) come after the linearity of Lebesgue integration.

In Folland's *Real Analysis* for example, linearity of Lebesgue integration of simple functions is firstly built up and the proof of MCT uses the linearity.

In Tao's *Introduction to Measure Theory*, the additivity
$$
\int_X   f+  g\  d\mu= \int_X\ f\ d\mu +\int_X g\ d\mu.
$$
for unsigned measurable functions are stated as a theorem, of which the proof is "highly nontrivial" and the MCT is not used in the proof.